# is there a gazebo or ros2 service/action to call SetActive from sensor?

Tags: gazebo, sensors, gazebo-plugin, service, action

context:
I have a simulation with a drone that have a camera. It is always "*on*" and i'd like to turn it "*on*" on demand only (from command line in a first step, then from a ros2 node).
In the SDF file of the camera sensor, I set `<always_on>1</always_on>`. Now I'd like to set it to 0 and activate it only when the user do something with the video.
I use Gazebo Garden, ROS2 Humble in Ubuntu-22.04 env.

I found that gazebo sensor has a [SetActive](https://gazebosim.org/api/sensors/7/classgz_1_1sensors_1_1Sensor.html#a3172f15c4f5860e8c276b394f75bae1d) method, but I can't understand how to get access to it.

The only service available related to camera and not gui related is `/world/warehouse_lanes/model/cis_drone_1/link/camera_link/sensor/camera/image/set_rate`.

I tried (without knowing if it made sense)

```bash
gz service --service /world/warehouse_lanes/model/cis_drone_1/link/camera_link/sensor/camera/image/set_rate \
    --timeout 2000 \
    --reqtype gz.msgs.Double \
    --reptype gz.msgs.Empty \
    --req 'data: 0.0'
```

but this resulted to "*Service call timed out*"

Any clue is welcome.